# Ubuntu 14.04 laptop keyboard doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, laptop, acer

I have Acer Aspire ES1-131-C77V with Ubuntu 14.04. One day keyboard has stopped working. It works only in BIOS and GRUB. It doesn'n work in OS, Recovery Mode and even LiveCD. The strangest thing is that FN + left/right arrow works well UNTIL i press any other key. USB keyboard works fine.

Output of lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57b3 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 21)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 22a3 (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 2284 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 21)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22cc (rev 21)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22ce (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 2292 (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

might be a codepage issue
  according to those

```
http://meabi.com/linux-keyboard-issue-with-lenovo-3000-y500-solution/
http://jbmoore61.blogspot.ro/2012/03/toshiba-satellite-l775d-s7340-and-linux.html
```

type

```
locale=en_EN i8042.reset
```

at the end of grubs kernel line

- when grub menu appears select the linux os > press "e" > go to the end of kernel line and edit > press "b" to boot
- or after OS loads > terminal > nano /etc/default/grub  > GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash locale=en_EN i8042.reset" > update-grub

Comment: Added this at the grub file but keyboard still doesnt work.